# JavaScript/Underscore get Min Max values for All Items in Object

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I'm having trouble figuring out how to get min/max value out of this object:

```
 "Prices" : {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
                "2014,1,11,0,0,0" : 1089,                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                "2014,1,12,0,0,0" : 1081,                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                "2014,1,13,0,0,0" : 1077,                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                "2014,1,14,0,0,0" : 1069,                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                "2014,1,17,0,0,0" : 1078,                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                "2014,1,18,0,0,0" : 1089,                                                                                                                                                                                                            
                "2014,1,19,0,0,0" : 1095
            }
```

I want to get the min/max of the numbers (Not dates) I was looking into _.pluck but it requires the key name but I don't know it. It's dates.... Any way to by pass that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_.values(prices)`.  With this approach you can then use `_.keys(prices)` and use that as a lookup for the correct key.

http://jsfiddle.net/x7eewf1d/2/

Although it may not be as efficient as other solutions, it will make clear to the next developer (who may be you) what is happening.

```
var prices = {
  '2014,1,11,0,0,0': 1089,
  '2014,1,12,0,0,0': 1081,
  '2014,1,13,0,0,0': 1077,
  '2014,1,14,0,0,0': 1069,
  '2014,1,17,0,0,0': 1078,
  '2014,1,18,0,0,0': 1089,
  '2014,1,19,0,0,0': 1095
};

var vals = _.values(prices);
var dates = _.keys(prices);

var min = _.min(vals);
var max = _.max(vals);

var minDate = dates[vals.indexOf(min)];
var maxDate = dates[vals.indexOf(max)];;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can either use a `for..in` loop or `Object.keys()` in vanilla Javascript, I'm sure Underscore has wrappers of some sort for those, too.

```
var p = {
  '2014,1,11,0,0,0': 1089,
  '2014,1,12,0,0,0': 1081,
  '2014,1,13,0,0,0': 1077,
  '2014,1,14,0,0,0': 1069,
  '2014,1,17,0,0,0': 1078,
  '2014,1,18,0,0,0': 1089,
  '2014,1,19,0,0,0': 1095
};
var min = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
var max = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
for (var prop in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    min = Math.min(min, p[prop]);
    max = Math.max(max, p[prop]);
  }
}
console.log('min: ' + min);
console.log('max: ' + max);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another plain JS option is using [*Object.keys*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.14) to get an array of the keys, [*map*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19) to get an array of the values, and finally [*Math.max*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.8.2.11) to get the maximum value:

```
var p = {
  '2014,1,11,0,0,0': 1089,
  '2014,1,12,0,0,0': 1081,
  '2014,1,13,0,0,0': 1077,
  '2014,1,14,0,0,0': 1069,
  '2014,1,17,0,0,0': 1078,
  '2014,1,18,0,0,0': 1089,
  '2014,1,19,0,0,0': 1095
};

Math.max.apply(Math, Object.keys(p).map(function(key) {return p[key]})); // 1095
```

and to get the minimum:

```
Math.min.apply(Math, Object.keys(p).map(function(key) {return p[key]})); // 1069
```

A for..in loop may be more code than the above, but it's probably a lot faster.